# Move multiple images on a page in different directions

Tags: javascript, php

I have multiple images on a page that are loaded dynamically using PHP. I want them to all move in different directions across the screen.

So far what I have, the images move in a random direction but all in the same position.

PHP:

```
<?php foreach($logos as $logo) { 
    $logoName = $logo['Logo_Link']; ?>
    <img class="imglogo" src="images/<?php echo $logoName ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    animateDiv();
});

function makeNewPosition($container) {

    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    $container = ($container || $(window));
    var h = $container.height() - 50;
    var w = $container.width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh, nw];
}

function animateDiv() {
    var $target = $('.imglogo');
    var newq = makeNewPosition($target.parent());
    var oldq = $target.offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

    $('.imglogo').animate({
        top: newq[0],
        left: newq[1]
    }, speed, function() {
        animateDiv();
    });

}

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

    var speedModifier = 0.1;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);

    return speed;
}
```

Comment: I think it would be more legible for `makeNewPosition` to return `{top: nh, left: nw}`, and then call `calcSpeed(oldq, newq)` ather than using arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made a loop in the `animateDiv` function

```js
animateDiv();


function makeNewPosition($container) {

    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    $container = ($container || $(window));
    var h = $container.height() - 50;
    var w = $container.width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh, nw];
}

function animateDiv() {
    var $target = $('.imglogo');
    for(let i=0; i<$target.length; i++){
       var newq = makeNewPosition($($target[0]).parent());
       var oldq = $($target[0]).offset();
       var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

      $($('.imglogo')[i]).animate({
        top: newq[0],
        left: newq[1]
      }, speed, function() {
        animateDiv();
      });
    }

}

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

    var speedModifier = 0.1;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);

    return speed;
}
```

```css
.imglogo{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imglogo"></div>
<div class="imglogo"></div>
<div class="imglogo"></div>
<div class="imglogo"></div>
<div class="imglogo"></div>
<div class="imglogo"></div>
<div class="imglogo"></div>
```